# Control Jersey logging from Java EE application on demand

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, logging, jersey, jax-rs

I need to enable Jersey tracing/logging dynamically from my Java EE 7 application. I don't have access to Jersey libraries, my only dependency is javaee-api 7.0.

I tried with logging.properties (JUL), but no success:

```
handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=ALL
java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format=%4$-7s [%3$s] %5$s%6$s%n

#All log level details
.level=ALL
org.glassfish.jersey.level=ALL
org.glassfish.jersey.tracing.level=ALL
client.Client.level=ALL
```

If I manage to configure it to log everything in console with java.util.logging properties, then I plan to reload logging properties with LogManager dynamically, but I'm stuck at that first step described above.

If it makes difference, application server is Payara 4 and implementation is Jersey 2.

Here's one use case that made me implement something like this:

If one vendor (3rd party system connected using REST) wants me to provide request/response with headers and payload from production system, I could raise the logging level on demand, log that required request and details and then lower the logging level back to normal. Otherwise I would need to use some monitoring app, or proxy in the middle which is not an option.

Comment: Is there a reason, why you insist on LogManager? If no, then maybe you should consider using slf4j and logback. It's really easy to setup a file listener with logback.

Comment: @JSONStatham I'm not allowed to add dependencies to application. Logging in application (and also in Jersey) is based on java.util.logging library so it seems like a logical point to start from.

Answer (score 1):

Found the mistake, I was missing the Jersey log handler in my logging properties file:
com.sun.jersey.handlers=java.util.logging.FileHandler

If I use this logging.properties file I get the wanted result:

```
handlers=java.util.logging.FileHandler
java.util.logging.FileHandler.level=ALL
java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format=%4$-7s [%3$s] %5$s%6$s%n

#All log level details
.level=ALL 

com.sun.jersey.level=ALL
com.sun.jersey.handlers=java.util.logging.FileHandler
java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern=debugging.log
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter=java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
```